# Create Drupal 8 Multisite on localhost

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I want to create a multisite Drupal 8 site.  I would like to keep the default site, and then add another site.  This is all being done on a WAMP stack and is on a locahost. These are the steps I have taken, but have not worked:

1. Downloaded most recent Drupal 8 and unzipped (and moved files) to www/my_primary_site
2. I created two databases in MySQL:  site1, site2
3. in the www/my_primary_site/sites folder, I did the following:

   a.  Created a folder called "my_second_site"

   b.  Created a file called sites.php.

   c.  In sites.php, I have this code:

   ```
     $sites = array(
       '8080.localhost.my_primary_site' => 'default',
       '8080.localhost.my_primary_site/my_second_site' => 'my_second_site',
     );
   ```

I then go to localhost/my_primary_site.  This brings me to the Drupal install (localhost/my_primary_site/core/install.php).  But, if I go to localhost/my_primary_site/my_second_site, it just redirects me back to localhost/my_primary_site/core/install.php.

I would expect that the second link would take me to a different install path.  Is this correct?  If not, how would I fix this?

thanks
jason

Comment: Did you follow this guide? https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multisite-drupal/multisite-drupal-8-setup

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to copy the default `settings.php` and `services.yml` to the new folder.

Try using the format of using `.` instead of `/`' like this:

```
 $sites = array(
    '8080.localhost.my_primary_site' => 'default',
    '8080.localhost.my_primary_site.my_second_site' => 'my_second_site',
  );
```

Make a symbolic link in your root directory that points to the main Drupal folder.

```
ln -s /drupal /my_primary_site/my_second_site
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$sites['site1.localhost'] = 'site1';
$sites['site2.localhost'] = 'site2';
```

Also, make sure you add this domain to your etc/hosts file:

> 127.0.0.1 site1.localhost
>
> 127.0.0.1 site2.localhost

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches :

1. Try using sysmlinks functions in file myfile.php

2.Using sites.php in /drupal/sites folder

```
$sites['site1'] = 'site1';
$sites['site2'] = 'site2';
```